# how does the numerator equal this?

Tags: laplace-transform

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rBdM.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyeSp.png)

How does $-(s^2 + 4) - (2s^2) = (s^2 - 4)$? I have tried different methods to get the result. However, I cannot figure it out.

This is taken out of uni notes in a Laplace Transform question.

Thank you in advance.

P.S: Could be something pretty simple but it seems to be slipping my mind.

Comment: The image and text do not agree. The image has: $$-\left[ (s^2+4)-(2s^2)\right]=-(s^2+4)+2s^2$$

Answer (score 1):

What you have is:

$$-\frac{(s^2+4)-(2s^2)}{(s^2+4)^2}=\frac{-(s^2+4)+(2s^2)}{(s^2+4)^2}=\frac{-s^2-4+2s^2}{(s^2+4)^2}=\frac{s^2-4}{(s^2+4)^2}$$

Comment: thank you very much, as i suspected pretty simple just been looking at it for too long

Comment: you are very welcome!